# Ctrl modifier key not working

Tags: 16.04, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have just installed a fresh new Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 and am having a weird problem.

The left and right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys are not working as modifiers. I can see them both doing what they should in xev but if I try and do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to clear my terminal or a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in a document to select all or any other key combo involving <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> it will not do anything.

I have looked through accesibility/universal access and keyboard settings to see if I can see anything obvious but I cannot and am completely stumped. Any ideas??

It appears when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in a terminal with a second key, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> for example, the terminal titlebar flashes in the same way it does if you press the down arrow when you are already at the bottom. Not sure if this is any help in diagnosing my issue or not??

I have tried using copy/cut/paste shortcuts in gedit and they don't have any noticeable effect.

Output of `xev` when I press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x13e00001,
    root 0x2d3, subw 0x0, time 192257122, (75,49), root:(75,75),
    state 0x10, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x13e00001,
    root 0x2d3, subw 0x0, time 192257222, (75,49), root:(75,75),
    state 0x14, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x13e00001,
    root 0x2d3, subw 0x0, time 192263578, (75,49), root:(75,75),
    state 0x10, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x13e00001,
    root 0x2d3, subw 0x0, time 192263658, (75,49), root:(75,75),
    state 0x14, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Interestingly the above is the result of two single keystrokes (one each left then right) is it normal to have two events per keystroke?

I have accidentally discovered that when I cut/copy/paste keyboard shortcuts do not work in either, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and scroll wheel still zooms in both libre office and chrome browser

**UPDATE**

I have stumbled across a fix. In the 'Keyboard and mouse' tab of gnome-tweak-tool. I enabled 'Show All Input Sources' and 'Show location of Pointer' and as if by magic <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is behaving as expected. Weird.

Comment: All of these are application-specific shortcuts. It would be odd if shortcuts involving Ctrl are broken in multiple applications, but it's worth checking that those shortcuts are actually enabled in the application configuration, e. g. in Gnome Terminal. Some applications have more or less hard-coded shortcuts, e. g. GEdit. What exactly is the output of `xev` when you press the Ctrl keys? Maybe they're wrongly assigned in your keyboard layout. Please [edit] your question to include the output and format it as a code listing (e. g. with the `{}` button in the editor toolbar).

Comment: Is this a laptop? If so, `state 0x10` and `state 0x14`  means the num lock was on. I would suggest trying ctrl+l combination with `xev` with & without num lock on.

Comment: Yes it is a laptop but with a full qwerty keyboard and numberpad. Yes num lock is on but that has always been the case on this machine, it has been running each release of Ubuntu since 12.04!

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

- Open gnome-tweak
- In the **Keyboard and mouse** tab of gnome-tweak-tool: 
  enable **Show All Input Sources** and **Show location of Pointer**.
- Restart session (I just restarted my system)

Comment: So having the Control Key not working seemed like a good default to the designers of Gnome?  (Scratches head)

Comment: On my ubuntu distribution the apt command doesn't find the gnome-tweak-tool

Answer (score 0):

I found that another app was mapping my control key to an accessibility control-window-grab that was activated. I simply mapped that to another unused key (from the drop-down list) and control worked as expected afterwards. Sometimes, you just have to go through ALL of your "tweak" settings to find out what stole the thing that you need to steal.