# CTRL Key not working on external keyboard, but is working on laptop keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 on it.  For some reason when I try to use the CTRL on a wireless dell keyboard nothing happens.  However everything works just fine when using the keyboard on the laptop.  Any suggestions?  I seem to remember it working previously.

Comment: Hello. Take the external keyboard to another computer and see if it still has this issue. You do not have a way to do that? Boot from a live media and try the keyboard there.

Comment: It is specific to that Dell keyboard, I tried another wired and wireless keyboard and it works fine.  Perhaps I need to install something?

Comment: Not for a keyboard the key is defective. Hence the keyboard is defective.

Comment: Fantastic thanks for your help, I plugged it into another computer and the same issue.  Opened up the keyboard and there's a short on the line to the ctrl keys.  Thank you again.

Comment: Great at the bottom of you question is an answer your own question button. Good idea to use that and enter you answer.

Comment: This topic seems to solve the question:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/791893/ctrl-modifier-key-not-working